# Making multiple axios request to get different data and input to multiple sections of the screen in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, react-native, axios

I am trying to get data and input it onto the same screen. For example, I will have a "POPULAR MOVIES" with 10 movies section and then underneath that, a "RECCOMENDED MOVIES", and 10 movies that are recommended to put into that section, and underneath that, a "NEWEST MOVIES" section so on and so on. But I dont know what are the best practices or how to implement that. I only know how to reach one endpoint at a time and getting data for that one point. As of now, I am only getting POPULAR MOVIES because it is the one that I have specified in my api call, but how to get other info? Do I need to make multiple requests in the same screen? Please see my code below. I have searched online but no one seems to ask such a question... lol. Anyways,  Thanks!

Im trying to get it like this! Where you have data for Featured, Staff Picks, New arrivals etc. 
[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";
import MovieItem from "../components/MovieItem";
import axios from "axios";
import {} from "@react-navigation/native"

const HomeScreen =({navigation})=> {
    const API_KEY1="....";
    const API_KEY2=".....";
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);


    useEffect(()=> {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY2}`);
            setMovies(response.data.results);
            console.log("MOVIESSS!!!", movies)
            console.log("RESPONSE.DATA!!!!" ,response.data)
            console.log("RESPONSE.DATA.Resultsssss!!!!" ,response.data.results.map(movie=> console.log(movie.original_title)))
        }

        fetchData();

    }, [])


    return(
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <Text>PPOPULAR MOVIES</Text>
            <FlatList data={movies} renderItem={({item})=> {
                return(
                    <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("MovieItem", {item})}>
                        <MovieItem item={item}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                )
            }}/>

        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems:"center"
    }
})

export default HomeScreen;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options,

1. change your three endpoints into one endpoint like `/feed` that returns something like this

```
{
  "popular" : [... list of 10 popular movies],
  "recommended": [... list of recommended movies],
  "newest": [... list of newest movies]
}
```

2. In your useEffect, add two more inner functions and call them synchrounously

```
const [recommended, setRecommended] = useState([]);
const [newest, setNewest] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=> {
  const fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY2}`);
  setMovies(response.data.results);
  console.log("MOVIESSS!!!", movies)
  console.log("RESPONSE.DATA!!!!" ,response.data)
  console.log("RESPONSE.DATA.Resultsssss!!!!" ,response.data.results.map(movie=> console.log(movie.original_title)))
  }
  const fetchRecommended = async () { 
    const resp = await axios("//getrecommended");
    setRecommended(resp.data])
  }
  const fetchNewest = async () { 
    const resp = await axios(//getnewest");
    setNewest(resp.data)
  }
  fetchData();
  fetchRecommended();
  fetchNewest();
}, [])
```

Although personally I would prefer option 1